# Pyqt5: QLabel displayed larger than its size()

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlabel

I have a QLabel on which I set a QImage using QPixmap. My image is of size 512x512 and I want it to stay at that size and not stretch/shrink.

After creating my QLabel, its size shows as 512, 512 but I can see that it has stretched. Maybe there is a way to prevent the stretching/size changing of a pixmap? What am I doing wrong here?

```
class ImageLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, image):
        QtWidgets.QLabel.__init__(self) 
        self._zoom = 1.0
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)   
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 512, 512)
        self.resize(512, 512) 

        # set image
        img = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(image)
        qimg = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
        self._displayed_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(qimg)

        # scale image to fit label
        w, h = self.width(), self.height()
        self._displayed_pixmap.scaled(w, h, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setScaledContents(True)
        self.setMinimumSize(512, 512)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, paint_event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self._displayed_pixmap)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(512, 512)

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, image):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self._image_label = ImageLabel(image)
        main_layout.addStretch()
        main_layout.addWidget(self._image_label)
        main_layout.addStretch()
        print(self._image_label.size())     # PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(512, 512)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
```

As you can see, I tried all variations off resizing.
When displaying, the label is actually the size of ~(1180, 512)

Comment: use `setFixedSize(512, 512)`

Comment: Thank you! Worked.